# How can I resolve a 'MultipleObjectsReturned' error when integrating Razorpay payment in a Python Django application?

Tags: python, django

we integrated razor pay payment gateway our python Django application while making payment getting beloow error -

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /paymenthandler/abcd@gmail.com/2/ get()
> returned more than one book_history -- it returned 5! Request
> Method:   POST Request
> URL:  http://spandiagno.com/paymenthandler/abcd@gmail.com/2/ Django
> Version:  4.0.5 Exception Type:   MultipleObjectsReturned Exception
> Value:     get() returned more than one book_history -- it returned 5!
> Exception
> Location: /home/ubuntu/main/span_diagno/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py,
> line 499, in get Python
> Executable:   /home/ubuntu/main/span_diagno/venv/bin/python3 Python
> Version:  3.10.6

Expected to fix payment issue in razorpay.